# Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces Version 1.1.1.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, prism

I'm deploying a WPF application using ClickOnce. The application runs fine on my machine from VS2012, but when I go to try to install it from ClickOnce, it shows the following error, which I understand is very common:

[image: Error Shown]

As I proceed to do further research, I REALLY cannot find why ClickOnce is asking for Prism.SharedInterfaces v1.1.1.0.

Here are a few of the things I checked:

[image: References and Properties of .dll inside VS]

I followed the path to the physical file and made sure the version within the properties of the .dll is 1.0.0.0.

I also opened the project solution file in notepad and looked for any sort of hidden reference that I could have missed. I've cleaned and rebuilt the solution a hundred times.

When I publish, I make sure that the file is included in the Application files.

Finally, I downloaded Process Explorer (which allows you to check what assemblies the application uses) and it still shows that SharedInterfaces.dll v1.0.0.0 is only being utilized.

Nowhere can I see Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces.dll v1.1.1.0 being referenced nor used. Why is ClickOnce asking for it?

I also found that you can add the following code in your App.config file to force version use:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.1.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but no luck.. I've run out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces.dll v1.1.1.0 inside one of the folders in the source file (Please note I did not start the project, I picked it up from a leaving contractor at the company I work for and was assigned to finish it). I'm guessing ClickOnce would somehow include the file or the version in the deployment and that's why it was asking for it. Once I added the v1.1.1.0 dll to the references and removed the v1.0.0.0 the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing the application, you need to go to the project properties and apply the settings to install the prerequisites.

[How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx)